# не выполняется запрос delete google rest api

Tags: java, android, retrofit, google-drive

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/";

public static OAuthServerIntf getOAuthClient(Context ctx) {

    Retrofit raCustom = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(getOAuthOkHttpClient(ctx))
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    OAuthServerIntf webServer = raCustom.create(OAuthServerIntf.class);
    return webServer;
}
```

**Вот интерфейс:**

```
public interface OAuthServerIntf {

    @DELETE("drive/v3/files/{fileId}")
    Call<Runnable> deleteFile(@Field("fileId")String fileId);

}
```

**Вот, где обрабатывается:**

```
 private void knopka (){
    OAuthServerIntf server=RetrofitBuilder.getOAuthClient(this);

    Call deleteFile=server.deleteFile("1avihf1YqkvD3Aop8qbZe9OVRUd_lSAHEbFsVzOLoL_8");
    deleteFile.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
            Log.w(TAG,"norm");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.w(TAG,"nenorm");
        }
    });

}
```

приложение падает на момент отправки запроса, появляются **exception**. ничего не возвращает. даже как то странно.

**вот сами exception:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:     @Field parameters can only
> be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)    for method
> OAuthServerIntf.deleteFile

Comment: Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: не работает запрос. хотя пробывал на полигоне google с этими параметрами все получалось, файл на сервере удалялся

Comment: нужно ли передавать в запрос токен(рефреш токен)?

Comment: еще раз.Что значит "не работает"? Ошибку выдает(какую?), ведет себя не так, как вам надо(как?), издает подземный стук, еще что-то?

Comment: приложение падает на момент отправки запроса, появляются exception. ничего не возвращает. даже как то странно

Comment: вот сами exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)
    for method OAuthServerIntf.deleteFile и java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. `ID` файла в запросе указывается в качестве части пути запроса, то вам надо использовать аннотацию `@Path` так:

```
@DELETE("drive/v3/files/{fileId}")
Call<Runnable> deleteFile(@Path("fileId")String fileId);
```

Comment: добавил, вот новый exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FormUrlEncoded can only be specified on HTTP methods with request body (e.g., @POST).
    for method OAuthServerIntf.deleteFile

Comment: @юрагибкин, попробуйте тогда `@Query` вместо `@Filed`

Comment: ошибка осталась та же... Если убрать аннотацию @FormUrlEncoded и оставить Query запрос проходит, но файл с сервера гугл не удаляется

Comment: А вроде понял. У вас ИД файла в пути. Так что надо @Path исполтзовать

Comment: огромное спасибо вам!!! все заработало! вы не знаете, где можно прочитать назначения анотаций field, query,path

Comment: когда получаю файл гет запросом, запрос выполняется, но когда удаляю файл - код ошибки 403 Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1FamU5Mw3uuuuxOfcTghouYRSdm00KPSjYKPPcERXwqo}

Comment: @юрагибкин, обновил ответ) Теперь вы можете отметить его "Верным"  нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа. А про аннотации в доке можно прочитать. Насколько я помню `Post` запросы используют `Field` и `Body`, `Query` для запросов в пути (те что после вопроса типа `request?key=value`)

Comment: @юрагибкин, видимо вам надо как-то авторизоваться

Comment: а как это сделать, не подскажите?

Comment: Ну... Это надо доку смотреть...

Comment: Проблема решилась. не было доступа к файлу, так как файл был скачан со сторонних ресурсов. правда я не знаю какой запрос нужно отправлять, чтобы получить доступ к редактированию или удаления файла